# Placing some sprites in Launchscreen.storyboard, is this possible?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, storyboard, launch-screen

Is there a way to place sprites in launchscreen.storyboard in sprite-kit game, for making some actions on them. It's like when player launches the game, he can see nice sprite animations. Or there are another ways to do things in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your `Launchscreen.storyboard` is like a static image, you have to create another `viewController` acting like a launch screen to do that.

Create a new `viewController` and set it as the entry point of your app, then add your stuff in it (sprites, animation etc.), and you can trigger an event to go to the next `viewController` when your animation is done, use a timer for example.

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the answer! I'll try this out.